# Does ZF prove the existence of a cardinal that is not reachable (through set union) from a given cardinal, for every cardinal?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, cardinals

Its consistent with ZF that every cardinal strictly bigger than $\aleph_0$ is *singular* ([Moti Gitik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal#Properties)).

> Is it provable in ZF that for every cardinal (initial von Neumann ordinal with respect to equinumerousity) number $\kappa$ there is a cardinal $\lambda$ such that every $\in$-confinal subset of $\lambda$ is strictly bigger in cardinality than $\kappa$?

Comment: No, that is exactly saying that the cofinality of $\lambda$ is bigger than $\kappa$. You start your question by noting that it is consistent that all cofinalities are $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. No I didn't say all confinalities are $\aleph_0$. I said that all cardinals are singlular, this mean that they are reachable through set union from strictly smaller cardinals, but those strictly smaller cardinals are not necessarily $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Since cofinality is necessarily regular, if all [uncountable] cardinals are singular, their cofinality is necessarily $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I don't know what you mean by confinality is necessarily regular. Perhaps that's the answer to my question then. Can you clarify this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cofinality of an ordinal $\lambda$ is the least ordinal $\kappa$ such that there is an unbounded subset of order type $\kappa$ in $\lambda$.

An immediate consequence of the definition is that if $\kappa$ is the cofinality of *any* ordinal $\lambda$, then the cofinality of $\kappa$ is $\kappa$.

And an immediate consequence of that is that cofinality is always a cardinal. So we can replace "order type $\kappa$" by "cardinality $\kappa$".

And an immediate corollary to all of that is that if every uncountable cardinal is singular, then the only possible cofinality is the only cardinal that $\sf ZF$ proves to be regular: $\aleph_0$. Therefore, in this case, every limit ordinal must have a countable cofinal sequence.