# Can $\omega_2$ be the order type of a countable union of countable sets of ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice, ordinals

Working in ZF(wihtout choice), according to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3890544/can-every-ordinal-be-reachable-from-aleph-0-in-zf?answertab=active#tab-top):  $\omega_2$ is not the countable union of countable sets.

> Can $\omega_2$ be the order type of a countable union of countable sets of ordinals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property of being a countable union of countable sets is preserved by bijections (just take the images of the sets under the bijection).  So, since $\omega_2$ is not a countable union of countable sets, neither is any set of cardinality $\aleph_2$.